# Are there side effects to using too much resistance for an LED?

Tags: led, resistance

I have a 9v battery and a standard red led from reference 1.7v drop and I want it to draw 20 ma also from reference. so id need a 365 resistor. to my understanding if i have too little resistance then the led will eventually burn out or worse.

But I have tried 1k and 10k resistors and the led still gives what to me is just as much light.(1/2 watt resistors)

What are the downsides of using higher resistances instead of a calculated 365 by ohms law?

If there are none, are there any advantages?

Or will it make no difference?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: I had a brain-fart and said you'd dissipate more power across a bigger resistor -- that's false. You'll just dissipate less power across the LED as Tom said.

Comment: I deleted it because it was incorrect and I didn't have anything to add that the other folks didn't already discuss. Personally I err on the side of picking bigger resistors (value-wise).

Comment: If the LED shines as brightly as you want it to with a higher than expected value of ballast resistance, then the only downside might be the loss of a few jobs at the LED factory because of the increased longevity of the LED and at the energy factory because of the megawatt-hours not needed to be generated

Comment: If your LED shines as brightly at less than a milliamp as when it has 20milliamps, then your reference isn't much good.  Can you give a part number for the LED?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will produce less light. Whether or not it is noticeably less depends on the LED.

Beyond that, you may get improved longevity as it will be dissipating less power - the current will be limited by the higher resistance.

You also end up with more tolerance to power supply ripple - higher voltages applied will not cause the LED to be driven out of spec.

Comment: May? Everything else equal, You will get improved longevity.

Comment: @Passerby unless you hit it with a hammer. Electrically it will help, but there are no guarantees something else won't happen to it in the mean time.

Comment: Splitting hairs? Talk about reducing "electrical fatigue" then?

Comment: I guess we could argue electromigration or other similar effects where the current density through a metal area measurable in angstroms / nanometers matters but we're beginning to argue about the lonegtivity of what is likely some random LED out of China destined for a breadboard somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should choose a standard resistance value that is close to your resistance. I think it should be 470 ohm. If you use more than that, the current in the circuit is decreased and you get less light.

If you use a resistor that is a little bit less than 365 ohm (i.e. 330 ohm), The light will be brighter but there is a possibility that the LED will wear out.

Answer (score -2):

You could also put a 150 ohm resistor in parallel (shunt) with the LED.  The LED will be dimmer but it will last longer.

Comment: If you like wasting precious battery power, yes, you could...

Comment: Sorry Tim, but a shunt resistor won't make any difference to the LED (unless the battery is reaching the limit of its current-sourcing ability).  The resistor will just waste power...

Comment: @bitsmack If we put a shunt resistor across the LED then to a first approximation the voltage across the LED will not change much so the current in the series resistor hardly changes so there is less current available for the LED. In practice the voltage across the LED falls slightly giving slightly more current in the series resistor but less in the LED. There is no advantage in doing this however if you want less current in your LED just use a bigger series resistance. As pointed out by Nasha this wastes power.

Comment: Call me a power waster, but it is a proven method to lengthen the life of LEDs.

Comment: @WarrenHill. We're thinking about two different things.  If there _is also_ a series resistance, then you're right that the current will split between the shunt resistor and the LED.  I thought that Tim Spriggs was recommending a shunt resistor _instead of_ a series resistor. In that case, both the LED and the shunt resistor will get the full battery voltage (and will draw their current independent of each other).

Comment: @bitsmack, yes-- shunting the LED .

Comment: I'm not arguing about using the series resistor.  where did you get that?

Comment: Hah, sorry! Maybe I'm a victim of "web chat fatigue" :)  I had answered Warren Hill's comment, then you answered one of mine, and it seemed to me that we weren't all seeing it correctly. I'll pull the last comment, and leave it at that. Take care!

Comment: cool beans, bizmark.